# Where do I go from here with my multi-class support build? (Life Cleric 3; Rogue 1; Shepherd Druid 2)

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing

I just need to pick your brains please. I'm playing in a D&D 5e party. Our GM is allowing us to multi-class and use feats. I am the main healer and the only one with Darkvision. I'm a Hill Dwarf, with Urchin background. Main stats Wis/Dex/Con (ok Cha but dire Int and Str).

Currently:

- Cleric - Domain of Life (3 levels)
- Rogue - [Mastermind] (in progress - 1 level so far; with expertise in
  Stealth and Perception)
- Druid - Circle of the Shepherd (2 levels)

I have chosen my classes and sub-classes but:

Where do I go from here - what is the best order to level up in the three different classes from now on?

#### Criteria are: Support Primary, skill versatility / stealth secondary

1. I want my main role to be support/heal the party.
2. I also want to be able to be versatile (using skills, Thieves'
   Tools; Poisoner's Kit) and sneak places (ambush, investigate,
   set/disarm traps; use my Wild Shape).

Comment: [This build seems familiar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZCIh_3b5K8)...

Comment: @ETgothome What is the level your campaign is likely end? Depending on the level, there might exist other options.

Comment: Hi Chpelink - I think my DM said around level 13, but he wasn't too sure about that.

Comment: For those who voted to close this, would it help if ETgothome included the optimization tag?  It seems to me, from the closing paragraph, that the character goal is support first, other stuff second, and the path forward given "state of the build so far" as stated in the question.  Or, does that tag not fit "what is the best way for me to go forward with a build that is at this condition" and only applies to "top to bottom" optimization questions?

Comment: Thanks - I've added the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Next level: Druid 3 for *Healing Spirit* to support your goals

> I want my main role to be support/heal the party.

*Healing Spirit* is one of the great healing spells in this edition of the game.

> Until the spell ends, whenever you or a creature you can see moves
>   into the spirit’s space for the first time on a turn or starts its
>   turn there, you can cause the spirit to restore 1d6 Hit Points to that
>   creature (no action required)... As a Bonus Action on Your Turn, you can move the spirit up to 30 feet to a space you can see.
>
> **At Higher Levels**. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd
>   Level or higher, the Healing increases by 1d6 for each slot level
>   above 2nd.  (XGtE)

Since you are multi classing with a higher level full caster class, cleric, you'll be able to upcast this spell.  Here are the spell slots you will have available:

> 6th: 4 1st, 3 2d, and 3 3rd.  (Spell Table, Multiclassing, PHB)

Your party will get up to 2d6+5 healing for each of your allies for each round of combat if you aren't too spread out and they are able to move into/through the healing spirit.  That's a very nice use of a spell slot.  You need to be a 3rd level Druid to get your hands on this spell.
Do it if your priority is to play the role of support/healer.  Note that since you took the Life Domain, you add 2 + the spell level to healing spirit's ability).

> **Disciple of Life**
>   Also starting at 1st Level, your Healing Spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st Level or higher to Restore Hit Points to a creature, the creature regains additional Hit Points equal to 2 + the spell’s level. (PHB, Cleric)

Using either a 2d or 3rd level slot, 1d6 + 4 or 2d6 +5 (depending on what spell level slot you use) is applied each time an ally taps into Healing Spirit's well of HP.

They keep fighting, and you keep healing. Teamwork, for the win!   If your dedication to being the heal-bot is complete, you can have up the Unicorn Spirit as a totem.

> In addition, if you Cast a Spell using a spell slot that restores Hit
>   Points to any creature inside or outside the aura, each creature of
>   your choice in the aura also regains Hit Points equal to your druid
>   level.(XGtE)

That said, I'd personally recommend having the Bear Spirit up during combat - IMO, it's a more complete support package once combat is in progress.

> Bear Spirit. ...
>   Each creature of your choice in the aura when the spirit appears gains Temporary Hit Points equal to 5 + your druid level {3}.   In addition, you and your allies gain advantage on Strength Checks and Strength Saving Throws while in the aura.

Givein each ally 5+3=8 temporary HP is more beneficial than adding 3 HP to each ally, and, if your martial allies are trying to grapple, shove, or break grapples, their attempts are enhanced.

#### Another benefit of Druid

One last benefit of taking another level in Druid: the 2d level spell *pass without trace.*  You can get your party past trouble, or into and out of various places with less trouble.

#### For skill versatility - cleric & druid help with that

> I want my main role to be support/heal the party. I also want to be
>   able to be versatile (using skills, Thieve's Tools; Poisoner's Kit)
>   and sneak places (ambush, investigate, set/disarm traps; use my
>   wildshape).

Druid and Cleric both have access to Enhance Ability at 3d level.

> Enhance Ability / 2 transmutation / Up to 1 hour   Classes: Artificer,
>   Bard, Cleric, Druid, Sorcerer (PHB)

The Cat’s Grace, Fox’s Cunning, and Owl’s Wisdom choices offer a PC advantage on Dexterity, Intelligence, and Wisdom checks.  If you really need help with an Intelligence check, make sure that you have Guidance as a cantrip from either Druid or Cleric cantrip lists.

#### Then what?

Next two levels in Cleric (to get to level 5) and then see if the campaign is still going.  You'll have 9 total levels at that point.  There will accrue an an ASI or Feat at Cleric 4, and then 3rd level spells arrive at Cleric 5.  (The Revivify Domain Spell might be an ally saver; at that level you can run into some pretty nasty monsters).  After getting those spells, another level in Druid (at 4 druid, you get an ASI or a feat and more flexible wild shape + swimming speeds) and then ... to taste.  A second level in Rogue will help with defense - you'll get Cunning Action that allows for a bit of moving around to avoid getting hit.

#### Mastermind looks like a better choice if you hit Rogue 3

The Mastermind Rogue archetype fills the support role better than Assassin. Your character can use a bonus action to give one of your martial allies advantage on an attack. Very handy.  (Thanks @Chepelink for the point on that, we did a one shot a couple of years back where I had a Mastermind rogue who like to give our Paladin advantage on attacks ... for us it worked great).

> **Master of Tactics**
>   Starting at 3rd Level, you can use the Help action as a Bonus Action. Additionally, when you use the Help action to aid an ally in attacking a creature, the target of that Attack can be within 30 feet of you, rather than within 5 feet of you, if the target can see or hear you. (XGtE)

Once you are into Tier 3 play(around level 11) you'll want to re-evaluate your Character goals.  That would be a good point to ask another question focused on higher tier play.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm thinking that the Assassin archetype for what he wants might not be the best rogue archetype. I think that Mastermind would work better. It might not have the poisoner's kit, but it has the help action as a bonus action and is ranged (it also has more goodies). Winning the initiative roll is everything for an assassin for his ability to trigger. high dex and alert quite useful for that. Instead, Mastermind have more general utility.

Comment: @Chepelink As a support, yeah.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  Thank you so much guys. It has been fantastic food for thought. I will definitely be taking my Druid to L3 to get *Healing Spirit*. I might take L2 in my Rogue along the way, too, because of the versatility of Cunning Action; and the archetype Mastermind is fantastic for my support role! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## You should take your next two levels in Cleric

Ability Score Increases are not to be scoffed at. If you increase your Wisdom Score, then you can choose more spells in both cleric and druid. Furthermore, any spells have their power based off of your Wisdom stat will be buffed, such as *Healing Word* or *Cure Wounds*.

At fifth level in Cleric, you will be unlocking 3rd-level spells, which gives a significant bump in versatility, unlocking spells such as *Revivify*, *Speak with Dead*, *Sending*, and *Clairvoyance*. Because you can change your spells around every long rest, this does push you towards being a great support character.

## Your progression in the future should something look like this:

- 3–5 levels in rogue
- 4 levels in druid
- 13–11 levels in cleric

Below is the reasoning behind these choices:

---

### 4 Levels in Druid

Druid is a terrific class, but is quite front-loaded. This is something to consider when multiclassing — you might get more benefits from focusing on other classes.
But at fourth level, Druid unlocks an ability score increase, has access to some terrific 2nd-level spells (such as *Pass Without Trace* and *Healing Spirit*), and improved wild shape choices.

### 3–5 Levels in Rogue

Looking at Rogue (Assassin), they have a terrific feature at third level called Assassinate. Furthermore, if you want to help support, the poisoner's kit and disguise kit may help your team in a pinch if there aren't others in your party with those proficiencies. Personally, I would stop there to progress more on your  spellcasting classes, especially if you want to focus on support.

But, if you *do* want another tantalizing Ability Score Increase, you should go four or five levels in rogue. The fifth level will delay your spellcasting progression even more, but will make you tankier and do more damage. Consider the benefits of:

- Ability Score Increase
- 3d6 sneak attack damage, which compounds with assassinate
- Evasion, which helps make you more tanky even in wild shape

Whether or not that is worth it will be up to you. A word of warning: most (if not all) beasts do not have a *finesse* or *ranged* attack available to use sneak attack with, thus you will not be able to use sneak attack in wild-shape form.

### 11–13 Levels in Cleric

Once you get to 10 levels in cleric, you will have their Divine Intervention feature, which is terrific.

If you push for 11 levels in cleric, you will have access to 6th level spells.

Cleric also has domain spells, further expanding your reservoir of spells prepared, and thus your versatility. Most of the Life Domain Spells seem to be right up your alley to boot.

If you decide to only go three levels in rogue as recommended, you will be able to unlock 7th level spells once you have 13 levels in cleric.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yeah, thanks for pointing that out! I always get 5th and 6th level spells mixed up, its 6th level spells that are considered in the "Masters of the Realm" tier of play (page 36 in DMG)

Comment: No vote either way here. The points are mostly solid, except for Rogue. I would not characterize Assassinate as "terrific". It's highly situational, and only works the first around of combat.

Comment: @Noltron000 Thank you for your response. It's been good food for thought. I decided to take +2 levels in Rogue but choose the Archetype Mastermind because it's support mechanism at L3 "Master of Tactics". But you answered my original question which I appreciated.